# why i got prefetch in header for pagination using list view?

Tags: php, yii2, typeahead.js

i am using yii2 listView widget to list some items, i have noticed that in the header there is `rel="prefetch"` and `rel="next"` , don't know why.

what is the point of having such these links in the header?
how could i disable this ?

Answer (score 1):

Prefetched data is fetched and processed on initialization. If the browser supports local storage, the processed data will be cached there to prevent additional network requests on subsequent page loads.

it is not enabled by default, enabling prefetch can be accomplished by just adding `rel="prefetch"` to a specific url.

**WARNING:** While it's possible to get away with it for smaller data sets, 
prefetched data isn't meant to contain entire sets of data. Rather, it should 
act as a first-level cache. Ignoring this warning means you'll run the risk of 
hitting [local storage limits].

When configuring `prefetch`, the following options are available.

- `url` – The URL prefetch data should be loaded from. **Required.**
- `cache` – If `false`, will not attempt to read or write to local storage and
  will always load prefetch data from `url` on initialization.  Defaults to 
  `true`.
- `ttl` – The time (in milliseconds) the prefetched data should be cached in 
  local storage. Defaults to `86400000` (1 day).
- `cacheKey` – The key that data will be stored in local storage under. 
  Defaults to value of `url`.
- `thumbprint` – A string used for thumbprinting prefetched data. If this
  doesn't match what's stored in local storage, the data will be refetched.
- `prepare` – A function that provides a hook to allow you to prepare the 
  settings object passed to `transport` when a request is about to be made. 
  The function signature should be `prepare(settings)` where `settings` is the 
  default settings object created internally by the Bloodhound instance. The 
  `prepare` function should return a settings object. Defaults to the 
  [identity function].
- `transform` – A function with the signature `transform(response)` that allows
  you to transform the prefetch response before the Bloodhound instance operates 
  on it. Defaults to the [identity function].